# Is a company e.g. Pfizer, singular or plural?

Tags: british-english, subject-verb-agreement, collective-nouns

Here is from an article from the [Economist](http://www.economist.com/news/science-and-technology/21659703-failure-publish-results-all-clinical-trials-skewing-medical/) magazine:

> One drug he talks about is an antidepressant called *reboxetine* (branded as *Edronax* by
>   **its makers**, Pfizer) that he used to prescribe to his patients.

Pfizer is a drug company. It is a singular noun.
Why is it described as its *makers*, which is plural?

Comment: It's common in BrE to refer to companies in the plural.  In AmE, the singular is used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The style guide of [The Economist](http://www.economist.com/style-guide/singular-or-plural) says:

> COLLECTIVE NOUNS
>
> There is no firm rule about the number of a verb governed by a singular collective noun. It is best to go by the sense--that is, whether the collective noun stands for a single entity or for its constituents.

So it is correct to refer to organizational names either as singular or plural but not both--that is, there should be a constancy in writing.

In this case the author wishes to emphasize the individuals of the company.