# Is "Greenplant are proud sponsors of..." correct? How is it different from "Greenplant proudly sponsors.."?

Tags: difference, grammaticality, singular-vs-plural

> Greenplant proudly sponsors

and

> Greenplant are proud sponsors of

(Greenplant is a business name. It consists of two sites and has a number of employees. However, for me the key aspect of this sentence is that the word Greenplant is singular. Is that correct? It would be good to understand the difference between the two sentences, because, I am being told that one way is right and the other is correct.

Comment: Welcome!   This question is very similar to [this one](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/62729/is-a-company-e-g-pfizer-singular-or-plural) .. asking if a **company is singular or plural**.

Answer (score 0):

Greenplant is a company *name*, so is neither singular nor plural.

Both versions are largely equivalent, and both used approximately as frequently as each other.